# Show the popads code only in mobile devices, how I do?

Tags: javascript, mobile, popup

I use the popads popunder in my site but i've one issues with it. That is happening on mobile devices, The pop is opening in a browser all the time and the user can't acess the other pages. So I think that it can be solved if I hidden the code on mobile devices, making it appear only in desktop. Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot, follow the code above:

PopAds.net Popunder Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _pop = _pop || [];
  _pop.push(['siteId', ###]);
  _pop.push(['minBid', 0]);
  _pop.push(['popundersPerIP', 0]);
  _pop.push(['delayBetween', 0]);
  _pop.push(['default', false]);
  _pop.push(['defaultPerDay', 0]);
  _pop.push(['topmostLayer', false]);
  (function() {
    var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    pa.src = '//c1.popads.net/pop.js';
    pa.onerror = function() {
      var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
      sa.src = '//c2.popads.net/pop.js';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
    };
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ! it worked for me! this will show ads in desktop only

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest == &quot;true&quot;'>
         (leave this empty)
<b:else/>
       (put your popads code here)
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!